# My query isn't populating data in Apex Charts but it works in Toad

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

```
    Select
    null link,
    a.Time_Frame "Start_Date",
    (a.Row_Number*(REGR_SLOPE(a.Failures, a.Row_Number) Over (Partition by a.State)) + (REGR_INTERCEPT(a.Failures, a.Row_Number) OVER (Partition by a.State))) Trendline

    FROM
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                     WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                     WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                     WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                END))  Row_Number,
     (Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                     WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                     WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                     WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                END) Time_Frame,
      count(job_id) Failures, State
    --FROM apps.NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V@util.world
    FROM NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V
    WHERE
    STATE = 1
    and
    (
    :P1_JOB_TYPE_CHOOSER = 'Workflow' AND INFA_TYPE_CODE = 'WORKFLOW'
    OR
    :P1_JOB_TYPE_CHOOSER = 'DSS' AND INFA_TYPE_CODE = 'DSS'
    OR
    :P1_JOB_TYPE_CHOOSER = 'MTT' AND INFA_TYPE_CODE = 'MTT'
    OR
    :P1_JOB_TYPE_CHOOSER NOT IN ('Workflow','DSS','MTT')
    )

    group by (Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                     WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                     WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                     WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                END), state
    ORDER BY State,(Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                     WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                     WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                     WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                END)
    ) a
    Group by a.Row_Number, a.Time_Frame,a.Failures, a.State
    order by a.State,a.Row_Number;
```

In the middle is source. This query works in Toad but when I move it to Oracle Apex App developer the chart won't populate data. The only change that  is made is I switch the FROM clauses around in the middle. I know that "apps.NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V@util.world" works as a source because I'm using it inside other queries in the app. If i get rid of the CASE/WHENS and switch them to just a single line like trunc(start_time) by itself, the data populates. Any help would be appreciated.

Table and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG 
( TASK_ID        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
, OBJECT_NAME    VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)
, JOB_ID         VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL
, INFA_TYPE_CODE VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
, RUN_ID         NUMBER(10)
, START_TIME     DATE
, END_TIME       DATE 
, STATE          NUMBER(1)
);

INSERT INTO NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG
(TASK_ID, OBJECT_NAME, JOB_ID, INFA_TYPE_CODE, RUN_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATE)
VALUES
( '000T0W0N0000000000000U'
, 'CampSync_ERP_SFDC_v1.2'
, '000T0WC1000000001I6W'
, 'WORKFLOW'
, NULL
, TO_DATE('5/22/2015 11:20:10','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
, TO_DATE('5/22/2015 11:21:02','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
, 1
);

INSERT INTO NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG
(TASK_ID, OBJECT_NAME, JOB_ID, INFA_TYPE_CODE, RUN_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATE)
VALUES
( '000T0W0N00000000000H'
, 'PMDM_ORA_ORA_ClnLoad_v1.0'
, '000T0WC1000000001J5X'
, 'WORKFLOW'
, NULL
, TO_DATE('5/24/2015 10:30:11','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
, TO_DATE('5/24/2015 10:32:34','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
, 1
);

COMMIT;
```

I found the solution. I'm not entirely certain why this made it work in Apex though:

```
             Select
             Null Link,
             tf.Time_Frame LABEL,
               (tf.Row_number*(REGR_SLOPE(count(data.job_id), tf.Row_number) Over (Partition by data.State)) + (REGR_INTERCEPT(count(data.job_id), tf.Row_number) OVER (Partition by data.State))) Trendline

                FROM APPS.NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V@util.world data
                ,
                (
        Select RowNum Row_number, Time_Frame
           from
            (    
             Select 
                 Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                         WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                         WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                         WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                    END Time_Frame
             From  APPS.NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V@util.world
             group by Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                         WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                         WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                         WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                    END
             order by 1
             )
        ) tf 
        where
        tf.Time_Frame = (Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                         WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(data.start_time)
                         WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(data.start_time, 'WW')
                         WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(data.start_time, 'MM') 
                    END)
        AND
        STATE = 1
                AND

              (
                :P1_JOB_TYPE_CHOOSER = 'Workflow' AND data.INFA_TYPE_CODE =  'WORKFLOW'
                OR
                :P1_JOB_TYPE_CHOOSER = 'DSS' AND data.INFA_TYPE_CODE = 'DSS'
                OR
                :P1_JOB_TYPE_CHOOSER = 'MTT' AND data.INFA_TYPE_CODE = 'MTT'
                OR
                :P1_JOB_TYPE_CHOOSER NOT IN ('Workflow','DSS','MTT')
              )
        group by tf.Time_Frame, tf.Row_number, data.State
```

Comment: this query is designed to give a trendline based on what time bracket they input. :P1_DATE_CHOOSER decides what the bracket is.

Comment: are you positive the bind variables have values in session state? What happens if you hardcode them?

Comment: How did you define the LOV/What values did you define for `P1_DATE_CHOOSER`

Comment: It works fine if I hardcode it, and it has values in the session state because other queries are using that same case/when logic to truncate start_time

Comment: Static:Daily,Weekly,Monthly,All       <---- that's what P1_DATE_CHOOSER's values are

Comment: not convinced on session state - did you open the popup and check? If you add an ELSE to the case, does it work? If so, signs still pointing to empty variables. What about p1_job_type_chooser?

Comment: I opened the session state at the bottom of the page and the variables check out. The same variables are being used by other charts on the page, and those other charts are populating just fine.

Comment: I suppose the LOV for job type chooser is similar to date chooser's

Comment: Also, since charts always execute an ajax call to get their xml, you may want to open up your browser's dev tools (I don't recommend IE, but you could do this with IE10). Open the network tab (or the console tab in firebug) and refresh the page. You want to look for calls to wwv_flow.show. One of those will pertain to your problematic chart. You  want to find that and inspect the return of that call. (disable other components while you debug if that makes it easier for you) What is returned? Is it xml? No errors in it?

Comment: I'm using chrome. Would i reach this information by inspecting the element on the problem chart's page?

Comment: Also, I started using the debug feature and I was getting these errors: message: Flash Chart error, ORA-00979: not a group by expr ORA-02063: preceding line from UTIL display location: ON_ERROR_PAGE is_internal_error: true apex_error-code: WWV_FLOW_FLASH_CHART.FLASH_CHART_ERROR, ora_sqlcode:-979, ora_sqlerrm: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expr ORA-02063: preceding line from UTIL error_backtrace: ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1825 ORA-06512 at "APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_FLASH_CHART5", line 3713

Comment: it is also worth reminding after i showed these errors that the exact same query worked in Toad with the only changes being switching from: NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V in toad to apps.NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V@util.world

Comment: In the debug, are you seeing any query statement? It might be apex which parses the query with some additional statements. Also, what sort of chart are you trying to produce? I think we may also be at the point where it may become interesting for you to provide a create table statement with the few necessary columns in it, and a couple records. So we could try to reproduce this.

Comment: Yes, the problem isn't isolated to any particular kind of chart because I tried to replicate the problem on different charts. I think Apex is not parsing my Case When's in the linear regression functions that oracle provides.

Comment: @Tom                                                                                                                                                                 CREATE TABLE NI.NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG
              (
      TASK_ID              VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
      OBJECT_NAME          VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
      JOB_ID               VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)        NOT NULL,
      INFA_TYPE_CODE       VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
      RUN_ID               NUMBER(10),
      START_TIME           DATE,
      END_TIME             DATE )

Comment: Here are a couple records: TASK_ID (000T0W0N0000000000000U, 000T0W0N00000000000H), OBJECT_NAME (CampSync_ERP_SFDC_v1.2, PMDM_ORA_ORA_ClnLoad_v1.0), JOB_ID (000T0WC1000000001I6W, 000T0WC1000000001J5X), INFA_TYPE_CODE ('WORKFLOW', 'WORKFLOW'), RUN_ID (NULL, NULL), START_TIME (5/22/2015 11:20:10 AM, 5/24/2015 10:30:11 AM), END_TIME(5/22/2015 11:21:02 AM, 5/24/2015 10:32:34 AM)

Comment: What kind of chart are you trying to create? 2D line? I have set up a sample here: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=21892:41 apex_demo/demo, and this chart works. I've also done it on my local instance (4.2.6) and it works. Not sure what is going wrong then. I don't have the view on the table though, I'm selecting on the table itself since I don't have the view's code.

Comment: @Tom I'm having trouble logging onto the link you sent. Do i use my OTN acct?

Comment: nevermind, i got it. I'm trying to create a 2D line. I don't see any points of data when I try to populate the table by selecting 'WORKFLOW' and then 'Weekly'

Comment: is there any way i can see how you are setting up the table and query to compare and contrast with my own work?

Comment: @Tom I was able to change the structure of the query and make it work. I'm still not sure why the other version was not working in apex though

Comment: Weird - Can't really say what caused this. I didn't change much in your query except for the table name instead of the view, and of course I changed the page item names around. I also used the LABEL and VALUE aliases for the columns.